# Spark dataframe - how to fill nulls with sequential integer values?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a pyspark dataframe such as this:

```
KEY    VALUE
---    -----
623    "cat"
245    "dog"
null   "horse"
null   "pig"
331    "narwhal"
null   "snake"
```

How can I transform this dataframe such that any `null` values in the `KEY` column are replaced with a sequence of integers starting at `1`?  Desired result is below:

```
KEY    VALUE
---    -----
623    "cat"
245    "dog"
1      "horse"
2      "pig"
331    "narwhal"
3      "snake"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you asked for Python, but maybe the equivalent in Scala will help. Basically, you want to use the `Window` function `rank` along with the function `coalesce`. First we define some test data:

```
val df = Seq(
  (Option(623), "cat"),
  (Option(245),"dog"),
  (None, "horse"),
  (None, "pig"),
  (Option(331), "narwhal"),
  (None, "snake")
).toDF("key","value")
```

Then we will `rank` all the instances of a `key`, then we will use `coalesce` to choose either the original `key` or the new `rank`, then drop the `rank` column we created just to clean it up:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val window = Window.partitionBy(col("key")).orderBy(col("value"))
df.withColumn("rank", rank.over(window))
  .withColumn("key", coalesce(col("key"),col("rank")))
  .drop("rank")
```

Comment: Do you know any guide about `Window`s in `Apache Spark`?

Comment: Not much specifically Spark, but the Spark function comes from Hive, so you can look at the Hive docs: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics